# Changing the array return of php/mysql function

Tags: php, mysql

I have this get_all function:

```
function get_all($query)
{
    $res = mysql_query($query);
    $arr_res = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
        $arr_res[] = $row;
    mysql_free_result($res);

    return $arr_res;
}
```

It returns this array of data, which is what I need, but I don't want the first item of each array "[0]" to be returned with it:

```
   Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => gallery-1-1310312288_logo.jpg
                [post_image] => gallery-1-1310312288_logo.jpg
            )

    )
```

How can I alter the function to drop this extra item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this line:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC))
```

By default mysql_fetch_array will return the numerical array index and the associative one - adding the second parameter will make the function only return the associate index.

Comment: or you can use explicitly `mysql_fetch_assoc` which essentially does the same thing.